# Change values from inputs on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have arrow button at my view

It changes values from left input to right

Some of html code

```
<ul>
<li>
  <div class="header">Från</div>
  <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][origin_text]" id="search_legs_0_origin_text" value="Köpenhamn (CPH), Danmark" class="field-1 airport_field" placeholder="Från" data-source="/autocomplete/origin/flight" data-id-element="#search_legs_0_origin_id" />
  <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][origin_id]" id="search_legs_0_origin_id" value="6547676" />
  <div class="quick-destinations hide-small"><div class="quick-link" data-text="Köpenhamn (CPH), Danmark" data-id="6547676">Köpenhamn</div>, <div class="quick-link" data-text="Stockholm (STO), Sverige" data-id="6540299">Stockholm</div>, <div class="quick-link" data-text="Bangkok Don Muang (DMK), Thailand" data-id="6547002">Bangkok</div> eller <div class="quick-link" data-text="London Heathrow (LHR), England" data-id="6540398">London</div>?</div>
</li>
<li class="icon"><img class="right_left_arrow" data-number="0" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/right_left_arrow-c0f7e54c0a61ac009de1b92fd2ff1a4f.png" alt="Right left arrow" /></li>
<li>
  <div>
    <div class="header">Till</div>
    <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][destination_text]" id="search_legs_0_destination_text" value="London (LON), England" class="field-3 airport_field" placeholder="Till" data-source="/autocomplete/destination/flight" data-id-element="#search_legs_0_destination_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][destination_id]" id="search_legs_0_destination_id" value="6540382" />
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is script that do it

```
$(".right_left_arrow").on("click", () => {
  var id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-number"))
  var tmp_txt = $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_text`).val();
  var tmp_id = $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_id`).val();
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_text`).val($(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_text`).val());
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_id`).val($(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_id`).val())
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_text`).val(tmp_txt)
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_id`).val(tmp_id);
});
```

For some reasons it not working.

When I click it, nothing showing in console.

Where can be problem?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I updated my post @Ele

Comment: You use wrong quotes. You can use `"` as you do and `'`.

Comment: You're using an arrow function: please know what you're doing before applying it to everything. When using an arrow function, the `this` in your callback no longer refers to the element that triggers it, but the lexical `this` (likely the `window` object).

Comment: Also make sure that you're using the correct syntax. In your example the quotes are in the wrong format **`** should be **"**

Comment: @AjAX. OP is using ES6, which is totally valid. Backticks are used as template strings.

Comment: Why it should be `""`? @toxazion

Comment: @Balance - ignore the comments about the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using arrow function, the context `this` is the enclosing context (Lexical this) where was declared, in your case the window object.

An alternative is using the event passed through the handler and get the clicked element using the attribute `currentTarget`.

```js
$(".right_left_arrow").on("click", (e) => {
  // Here you can use e.currentTarget
  var id = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).attr("data-number"))
  
  var tmp_txt = $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_text`).val();
  var tmp_id = $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_id`).val();
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_text`).val($(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_text`).val());
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_origin_id`).val($(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_id`).val())
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_text`).val(tmp_txt)
  $(`#search_legs_${id}_destination_id`).val(tmp_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><ul>  <li>    <div class="header">Från</div>    <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][origin_text]" id="search_legs_0_origin_text" value="Köpenhamn (CPH), Danmark" class="field-1 airport_field" placeholder="Från" data-source="/autocomplete/origin/flight" data-id-element="#search_legs_0_origin_id"    />    <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][origin_id]" id="search_legs_0_origin_id" value="6547676" />    <div class="quick-destinations hide-small">      <div class="quick-link" data-text="Köpenhamn (CPH), Danmark" data-id="6547676">Köpenhamn</div>,      <div class="quick-link" data-text="Stockholm (STO), Sverige" data-id="6540299">Stockholm</div>,      <div class="quick-link" data-text="Bangkok Don Muang (DMK), Thailand" data-id="6547002">Bangkok</div> eller      <div class="quick-link" data-text="London Heathrow (LHR), England" data-id="6540398">London</div>?</div>  </li>  <li class="icon"><img class="right_left_arrow" data-number="0" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dzwdseno3/image/asset/right_left_arrow-c0f7e54c0a61ac009de1b92fd2ff1a4f.png" alt="Right left arrow" /></li>  <li>    <div>      <div class="header">Till</div>      <input type="text" name="search[legs][0][destination_text]" id="search_legs_0_destination_text" value="London (LON), England" class="field-3 airport_field" placeholder="Till" data-source="/autocomplete/destination/flight" data-id-element="#search_legs_0_destination_id"      />      <input type="hidden" name="search[legs][0][destination_id]" id="search_legs_0_destination_id" value="6540382" />    </div>  </li>
```

Comment: It fixed it. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

You are using arrow function, which means the `this` within the callback of the click event does not refer to the element itself, but to the lexical `this` (i.e. the context in which the click event was bound), which is more often than not the `window` object.

Just use regular anonymous function :) just because you can use arrow function does not mean you *have* to use it:

```js
$(".right_left_arrow").on("click", function() {
    // Rest of your logic here
    // `this` will refer to the DOM element that triggers the click event
});
```